# 'position: fixed' is not applying in Samsung S3

Tags: html, css, popup

I am using a pop up in my site and I have applied a .gif while loading the image. I want that image fixed in the center of the screen. I'm using the following CSS:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
bottom: 0;
display: block;
height: 100px;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
border-radius:25px;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

It's fine in all devices and desktop except Samsung S3.

Do we have an alternative to `position: fixed`.

Comment: Where you have fixed position? I see absolute only.

Comment: panther comment is justified, but u can try this:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Try `margin:0 auto;` instead of `margin: auto;`

Comment: sorry, It's position:fixed insted of absolute, my mistake :/

Comment: @Gunaseelan margin 0 auto isn't working

Comment: @hussainnayani Please provide a fiddle

Comment: I can 100% confirm position:fixed works on samsung galaxy s3 native browser.

Answer (score 0):

When running into such problems you can check with http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed
Also you should declare directives such as top, bottom, left, right after the position and suppy a measurement to your 0

for example

```
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
display: block;
height: 100px;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
width: 100px;
border-radius:25px;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it's solutions. I've added a parent Div before that div. I've applied the following styles on parent div and applied position absolute on child div. And it's fixed. Thanks to all for support.

```
position:fixed;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
display: block;
```